# How to persist newly added claims to existing HttpContext user in Asp.Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am *new* to .Net Core and have configured authentication as follow in **Startup.cs** file -

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // To be able to access HttpContext
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();            

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(o => o.LoginPath = "/login");

        // Most of the code removed for brevity            
    }
```

After user login, we authenticate the user by -

```
public static async Task AuthenticateUserAsync(HttpContext httpContext, AuthorizedUser authorizedUser)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, authorizedUser.UserUid.ToString()),
            new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.CompanyGuid, authorizedUser.CompanyUid.ToString())
        };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            // Refreshing the authentication session should be allowed.
            //AllowRefresh = <bool>,

            // The time at which the authentication ticket was issued.
            IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,

            // The time at which the authentication ticket expires. A 
            // value set here overrides the ExpireTimeSpan option of 
            // CookieAuthenticationOptions set with AddCookie.
            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),

            // Whether the authentication session is persisted across 
            // multiple requests. When used with cookies, controls
            // whether the cookie's lifetime is absolute (matching the
            // lifetime of the authentication ticket) or session-based.
            IsPersistent = false,

            //RedirectUri = <string>
            // The full path or absolute URI to be used as an http 
            // redirect response value.
        };

        await httpContext.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
            authProperties);
    }
```

In some service class, we retrieve portal information and tried to save it in claims as follow -

```
public async Task AddPortalToCurrentUserClaimsAsync(Guid companyUid, Guid userUid)
    {
        var portal = await _unitOfWork.Portals.All().FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.CompanyUid == companyUid && p.UserUid == userUid).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (portal == null) return;

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.PortalId, portal.Id.ToString()),
            new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.PortalName, portal.Name)
        };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);
    }
```

When I tried to retrieve this claim in further requests, I get null.

```
var portalId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(CustomClaimTypes.PortalId);
var portalName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(CustomClaimTypes.PortalName);
```

How I can get these newly added claims to persist in further requests?

Comment: Looking for a Solution for this problem

Answer (score 3):

I read from the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1) that share

> To create a cookie holding user information, construct a
> `ClaimsPrincipal`. The user information is serialized and stored in the
> cookie. `SignInAsync` creates an encrypted cookie and adds it to the
> current response. If `AuthenticationScheme` isn't specified, the
> default scheme is used.

So, you cannot add claims to already created `ClaimsPrincipal` as claims have already been stored in cookies.

The **solution** that work for me was to create new `ClaimsPrincipal` and create new cookie as -

```
public async Task AddPortalToCurrentUserClaimsAsync(Guid companyUid, Guid userUid)
        {
            var portal = await _unitOfWork.Portals.All().FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.CompanyUid == companyUid && p.UserUid == userUid).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (portal == null) return;

            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userUid.ToString()),
                new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.CompanyGuid, companyUid.ToString()),
                new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.PortalId, portal.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.PortalName, portal.Name)
            };

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                IsPersistent = false
            };

            const string authenticationType = "Cookies";
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, authenticationType);
            await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(authenticationType, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Claims are only added on persisted in the ClaimsPrinciple/User if `SignInAsync` has been called again. So, your first claims will be found because that are added before the user is signed in. However, as you're adding more claims, they won't be "saved" as the user's identity has not been reset.

If you're adding more claims, prior to the initial sign in, this should work:

```cs
var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
    IsPersistent = false,
};

await httpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User,
    authProperties);
```

Comment: I am *adding* more claims **after** sign in. I tried your [way](https://prnt.sc/uanzq2) and got error as *SignInAsync when principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false is not allowed when AuthenticationOptions.RequireAuthenticatedSignIn is true.*

Comment: ^^ That error is shown most likely because AddPortalToCurrentUserClaimsAsync is being called before login. Or while the user isn't logged in.

Comment: I run **AddPortalToCurrentUserClaimsAsync** immediately after *AuthenticateUserAsync* based on some conditions and sometimes not.

Comment: What if you were to modify your `AuthenticateUserAsync` method to include the portal claims?